# ansible - Could not recursively set attributes on <remote directory> 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'

Tags: python, ansible

I have an ansible script that prepares the webserver for website deployments.

I don't know of any ansible update or change in the ansible scripts but I suddenly get the following error:

```
fatal: [<server>]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not recursively set attributes on /var/www/<path>. Original error was: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'"}
```

I also don't know of any notable changes in the file structure that is already on that server (those tasks are all green normally because the folders are already existing)

```
- name: add parent dir
  file:
    path: "{{parent_dir}}"
    state: directory
    mode: "{{mode}}"
    owner: "{{user}}"
    group: "{{group}}"
    recurse: yes       # Works when I remove this line
```

Those tasks work as intended when I remove "recurse: yes" but I added this to ensure that also existing files in that directory always have the given permission.

**Any idea how to fix/debug this?**

Additional info that might be important:

The task is inside an `add_www_folders.yml` that is included in the following tasks:

```
- name: folder structure for production
  include: add_www_folders.yml
  become: yes
  vars:
    parent_dir: /var/www/<website>/production
    user: deploy     # deploy user is owner
    group: www-data  # www-data can read
    mode: '0750'     # no permissions for anyone else


- name: folder structure for staging
  include: add_www_folders.yml
  become: yes
  vars:
    parent_dir: /var/www/<website>/staging
    user: deploy     # deploy user is owner
    group: www-data  # www-data can read
    mode: '0750'     # no permissions for anyone else
```

Infos about my ansible

```
ansible 2.10.8
  ...
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
```

and

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are running the task on a directory which contains too many subfolders/files to be handled recursively. I'd bet the origin is that your directory has grown over time. Simply try this over a smaller directory to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You are kind of right...see my answer. The link is not circular but maybe the recursion becomes to deep because of it

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

Unfortunately, I still don't know what changed, as the directory includes this symlink for months or years but the problem was a link in that directory tree.

Changed the task to not follow this link

```
- name: add parent dir
  file:
    path: "{{parent_dir}}"
    state: directory
    mode: "{{mode}}"
    owner: "{{user}}"
    group: "{{group}}"
    recurse: yes
    follow: no     # <--- fixed by not following a linked dir
```

Comment: [`follow: yes` is the default since ansible 2.5 and was `no` before](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-follow) in case this helps your understand what happened.